# Android: How should I structure my Activity if I need to get an item and title from a remote db?

Tags: android

I am curious what is the best way to design an activity that simply makes a remote call and gets an item_name and item_description and needs to display that to the screen.

I was thinking about doing a hack of a ListView, but it seems that it isn't really intended for that.

What I really need is to be able to update 2 fields with the data I get back from the db. What is the best way to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be have a background task handle making the remote call (`AsyncTask` should take of that for you).  Since an Activity is pretty much the controller for the UI, it would best to keep that kind of heavy lifting off the main thread.

There multiple classes designed for making HTTP requests (`DefaultHttpClient`, `HttpURLConnection`, among others).  After that, Android also makes it easy to work with JSON (my preference) or XML.

Once you have the data from your HTTP request, you can have thebackground task update the UI (via your Activity) pretty much anyway you want.

- [Android Reference for AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

**UPDATE**:

One solution would be to create a listener interface, for example:

```
public interface MyHttpListener {
    public void updateUI(Myobject obj);
}
```

Have the Activity implement this interface.  In your AsyncTask, at some point before calling `execute()`, add a listener to the task maybe as part of the constructor:

```
public class MyTask extends AsynTask() {
    .
    .
    .
    MyHttpListener myListener;
    .
    .
    .
    public MyTask( MyHttpListener listener /* other parameters if needed */ ) {
        myListener = listener;
        // other set up
    }
}
```

Since the onPostExecuteMethod() runs on the UI thread, you do something like:

```
public void onPostExecute(MyObject obj) {
    myListener.updateUI(obj);
}
```

If your Activity implements this interface, that would be the best place to update the UI:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements MyHttpListener {
    .
    .
    .
    public void updateUI(MyObject obj) {
         // do what you need in the UI
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: ah yeah, I am already doing those things like AsynkTask and DefaultHttpClient. What I meant is how do I update the view once I get the items?

Comment: thanks for the nice write-up, I accepted the answer, but one more Q...how do I actually update the UI? Thats really what I was confused about.  Since the ui elements are often declared as final, I am not sure how to make them dynamically updated.

Comment: Don't declare them as final.  I've never had a problem with UI properties that were not declared as final.   As to how to actually update the UI, it depends on how you want to present.  Based on your question, using a couple of TextViews might do the trick, and setting their text properties might do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You would update the values of the TextView via tvText.setText(variable); and this would take place in the onPostExecute of your AsyncTask